# How to make SmoothScroll for website pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website and I have a question. My customer wants to make a more smooth scrolling on the site. For example, the browser chrome, has a special extension [SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en). Prompt me if there is something similar to a website, can any script or a library?

Comment: **[Please don't hijack my scroll.](http://marketblog.envato.com/web-design/scroll-hijacking/)** Do tell your client to consider the bad User Experience. Asking for a library recommendation isn't really what StackOverflow is about. Just use a search engine for this one.

Comment: @RowanFreeman, Ok, thanks for answer!

Comment: This one's much smoother than the accepted answer : http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i get your question can offer you to check this repo here: 
[Smooth Scrolling](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll)

You can declare STEP, SPEED, EASE, TARGETS...it is a pretty good library :)
And you have the Browser and os detection functionality